Наибыстрейший способ проверки числа на чётность
При решении алгоритмических задач на LeetCode, часто возникает потребность в микрооптимизациях.
Я понимаю, что с точки зрения читаемости кода наилучший способ для определении чётности это проверка остатка от деления:
if(n%2==0){ }

Но с точки зрения скорости выполнения, разве логическое умножение не будет быстрее?
if(n&1==0){ }


Скорее всего, компилятор сделает один и тот же код вроде test  eax,1  jnz  Odd . На leetcode важнее придумать алгоритм с хорошей сложностью и учесть все хитрые случаи

@MBo я на SO видел информацию, что по крайней в java код компилируется в различные инструкции.

Посмотрите: https://godbolt.org/z/G6eseKT3T

@MBo да, действительно, оформите как ответ?

Посмотрим, что сделает компилятор из этого кода: ассемблер справа.
Получается, что для обоих случаев сгенерируется одно и то же:
 test     al, 1
 jne      SHORT G_M29322_IG05

В любом случае, такие микрооптимизации стоит оставлять на самый конец.
При решении задач на leetcode и подобных стоит обдумать по очереди:

алгоритм, обеспечивающий наилучшую сложность - как вычислительную, так и по памяти
наиболее оптимальные структуры данных
минимизировать операции  выделения памяти, если объём данных велик
применять функции из системных библиотек вместо ручной реализации - они могут дать существенный выигрыш, например, в Python (поскольку реализованы на C)
тут уже можно на уровне отдельных операторов вылавливать проценты производительности


Я бы ещё добавил, что следует скептически относиться к... (как бы так потолерантнее сказать, чтобы не забанили). К статистическим показателям скорости и потребления памяти. Если Вам показали, что Ваше решение бьёт 70% остальных, зайдите в подробности статистики и посмотрите не на проценты, а на реальные значения. Скорее всего, окажется, что все решения более-менее одинаковы.
